# Кеширование для подраздела сайта в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, кэширование

Есть сайт, на нем раздел, в котором требуется не кешировать какие-либо ресурсы, в отличии от других разделов.

Допустим я хочу исключить для обработки раздел /admin и все в него входящее. Причем admin - это не директория файлов, соответственно создать его и положить туда другой htaccess нельзя. Возможно ли включение директив по маске в REQUEST_URI?

Мой htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

#GZIP
AddEncoding gzip .gz
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.gz [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

#GZIP
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

ServerSignature Off

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
#кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
</FilesMatch>
#кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>
#кэшировать флэш и изображения на месяц
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
#отключить кэширование
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
    Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
#по умолчанию кеш в 5 секунд
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
#кэшировать флэш и изображения на месяц
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
#кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
#кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 43200 seconds"
#кэшировать xml файлы на десять минут
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>

<files "\(admin)" >
AuthType Basic
AuthName «Prompt»
AuthUserFile /pub/home/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</files>
```

Comment: В `Files` или в `FilesMatch` не пробовали обернуть команды кэширования?

Comment: Спасибо за желание помочь, проблема как оказалось была в другом, ответ от меня ниже

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось что проблема была не в кешировании всего и вся, а конкретно редиректов.
Нужно поменять

```
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
    Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
```

на

```
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, max-age=0"
</FilesMatch>
```

Причина возникновения: В админке есть кнопка создать новый товар, она вида: /admin/catalog/create?category=2969
при нажатии на нее действие передается в контроллер, который создает новый товар под нужным разделом и делает редирект на страницу его редактирования вида: /admin/catalog/7832/edit

Так вот раньше редирект бросался в кеш клиента и при попытке создания нового товара, браузером выполнялся редирект из кеша на товар созданный ранее в обход контроллера создания товара.